# Import spreadsheet cell values into Scribus

Tags: scribus

I'm trying to design some name tags in Scribus and have a list of names and departments that I'd like to automatically import Scribus, creating a new name tag (i.e. a new page with the same design) for each data point. Is there a way to do that with an LibreOffice Calc Spreadsheet and Scribus 1.4.4?

Additionally, is it possible to set the attributes of frames (like background color) on each page according to a certain integer and/or boolean value of the according data point?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while Scribus is graphic design software this question has nothing to do with graphic design.

Comment: Similar questions on data  driven design are happily accepted and answered when the product in question is Adobe based.
Feels as if the mods are quick to close Q's beyond their scope of experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all completely achievable using Scribus Generator. http://www.ekkehardwill.de/sg/

I regularly create certificates with data merged from csv files. I've personally never used external data to change colours or images but it's all possible and I'm sure the docs will guide you through.